# Magento error - Mage registry key "_singleton/license/module" already exists

Tags: php, magento, installation, singleton

I have stumbled upon this error while reinstalling a backup from Installatron and I can't seem to make it go away.

I have encountered this error as I was doing this.

1. Update Magento using Instrallatron to 1.9.1
2. Found it to mess with all the CSS and as we don't have the web guy in office at the moment...
3. Delete the site.
4. Re-install the installatron backup created just before update.

The error occurs in both frontend and backend.

I have read some other posts regarding singleton errors so...
- tried flushing the cache (delete everything in var/cache folder) : doesn't work
- Went to the compiler and noticed it was disabled to tried & running the compiler : also doesn't work

Any suggestions?

The full trace is

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/license/module" already exists

Trace:
#0 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/lice...', false)
#2 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(21667): Mage::getSingleton('license/module')
#3 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(2616): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Diagrams.php(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(1966): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Diagrams->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(27977): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#9 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(1966): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(27977): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(27993): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#12 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(27760): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#13 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(27726): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#14 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(27731): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#15 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(13941): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#16 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(13866): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#18 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#19 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(14015): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#20 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(18399): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#21 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(17933): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/includes/src/__default.php(20705): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}
```

Edited April 27.

There is a new trace which is a little different to the one I had before. The end result is the same. It calls for singleton/license/module and fails...

```
#0 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/lice...', false)
#2 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('license/module')
#3 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(943): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('js_cookies', true)
#7 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml()
#8 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sytccoma/...')
#9 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#10 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#14 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/1column.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#15 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sytccoma/...')
#16 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#17 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#21 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#22 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#23 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#24 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#25 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#26 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#27 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#28 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#29 /home/sytccoma/public_html/funketcomau/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#30 {main}
```

Edited Apr 28

Thanks to zhartaunik I have found that this issue is related to one of my extensions... I have asked the developers to get back to me with a solution... if I don't get an answer back, I will post the config.xml here...

Thanks

Comment: Here you find a nice explanation of the source of this problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/51367/14528

Comment: Hi Thanks... I have read this but it doesn't give a solution... I have tried changing the Mage::getSingleton method to Mage::register method but this doesn't help either...

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue & later on i got the solutions. I was **overriding customer account page(login)** & my module name was Customer due to which it was conflicting later i deleted it & create a new module named `Customeroverride`
& now it is working fine.

PS : Please do not create module name on existed one.

Answer (score 0):

open includes/config.php and put # before following row:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

**upd.1**

When you see following lines in you

```
/includes/src/__default.php
```

It can happen **only when your compiler is enabled**! Try to check:

- native and other caches are disabled / cleaned
- is it really that magento? Maybe you call some another? Check your core_config_data for 'web/unsecure/base_url' value.

**upd.2**

I have found one more interesting solution. When magento call in some place this code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('license/module')
```

According to singleton pattern magento allow create only one instance of this object. Magento achieve that using Mage::registry. Most probably you have following situation:

1. 1st call of `Mage::getSingleton('license/module')`. Magento can't create this object and put in registry smth like `false`
2. 2nd time magento call this existing registry and see there `false`
3. After that magento trying to create registry again, but this regirsty has `false` value and you are getting an error.

To resolve this problem:

- you can disable this extension
- if you need to use this extension and don't know how to resolve this problem - copy it's config.xml (model part) to your first post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
 
I have tried it but the 2 code lines in the file were already commented out.
This method was unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. The compiler is definitely disabled. I've checked that... I have cleaned out var/cache folder and not sure wht you mean other caches. And there is only 1 installed CMS on this site and its magento... core_config_data value is correct.

Comment: Hi I've updated my post. It is no longer calling for /includes/src/__default.php but the error is still the same

Comment: Most probably I understand your problem

Comment: The problem is I don't know which extension is causing this! So i don't know which config.xml I need to copy for you...

Comment: try to search in your code this: license/module. Most probably you created some module and copied config.xml from some site and didn't replace values on yours. And this temp license/module causes an issue. If you use console - type following: grep -rni 'license/module'

Comment: Hi I found the issue to be with one of our extension. I have asked the developers to get back to me with a solution, if I don't hear back from them I will have to rely on your help again... Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. It also was good experience for me, as the problem is popular and most of people tell that problem is in cache. As we can see, not only in cache.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been now resolved.

The issue was related to an extension and its files being removed from the server due to an encryption which made the server antivirus to kick in.

Thanks for all your help especially to zhartaunik who enabled me to pinpoint the issue.